# NPM installation error of github repository

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, visual-studio-code

I am trying to clone and install this repository [UpStarMusic](https://github.com/StephenGrider/UpStarMusic) for a udemy course.

I have node version of 8.1.2 in my windows 10 with latest VisualStudioCode editor.

When I used npm install into the clone directory I am getting a following error

[Detailed Error Log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25028759/)

Errors are at the bottom of this log file.

How to get out of this mess?

**Update 1**:

I have installed build tools and now I am getting following electron error.

[Electron Error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25033250/)

**Update 2**

Starting command prompt as administrator

[image]

changing directory path and building project[image]

Comment: It's caused by node-sass, refer to this issue https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1985, try to update node-sass to the latest version (4.5.2) and see if it works. And if it doesn't, as node-sass may use node gyp to compile, make sure you install all the toolchains for node gyp: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Comment: It's a permission error, try run as admin

Comment: Please see my updated post I did as you suggested but no progress.. still getting electron error?

Comment: Do as it told, delete node_modules/electron and run npm install again, you have to run as admin, of course. Before install electron, you may have to install the prerequisites on Windows of electron list here https://electron.atom.io/docs/development/build-instructions-windows/